# react-native run-ios fails - Could not find simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.55.3
- Xcode : 10.2.1

I am trying to get a certain react-native project to build and run for the first time from my system using `react-native run-ios`.

I get :

> Found Xcode workspace App.xcworkspace
>
> Could not find iPhone 6 simulator

I looked for the different answers here but they didn't help me solve my problem (I changed the condition in `node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js`)

What's the meaning of this error ?
How to get the project to build and run ?

Thanks
Yaron

Comment: Have you already open a simulator via Xcode ? I personnaly run ios app by clicking the "run" button on Xcode, no need to run command.

Comment: I tried but the build fails.  Might be an issue with cocoa-pods. But anyway, couldn't build from there.

Comment: Run the simulator first and then try.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after updating to the latest Xcode.

[image: After simulator update/installation]

I went to the Download simulators, chose the newest one, and after it got downloaded and installed, I got back the devices you see in the screenshot